# Mongodb - MapReduce concatenated values instead of summed

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've sucessfully used Mongodb and MapReduce to aggregate a sales statement of over 5million lines down to around 60k. Very happy with the results but am puzzled by one line in the results where is seems to have concatenated the result instead of summing it, so i've ended up with a value field containing " 0.00590100000000.0059010.133150000000.0053100.002960.043208000.00189"

Has anyone experienced this before?

On close analysis of the lines involved in the raw statement, I can't see anything that would have caused it as they appear to be exactly the same. There are even values for the same identifier that have been summed.

My code is as follows, can anyone spot anything that might be causing it? Like I say, it's only 7 lines from a raw statement of 5.2 million so accuracy is pretty good, it's just not spot on and I know it will bug me.

```
mongoimport -d test -c sales --type csv --file sales_rawdata.csv --headerline

var mapFunction1 = function() {
                       emit({video_id: this.video_id, isrc: this.isrc, country: this.country}, this.amount_payable);
                   };


var reduceFunction1 = function(keyIsrc, valuesAmountPayable) {
                        return Array.sum(valuesAmountPayable);
                    };

db.sales.mapReduce(
        mapFunction1,
        reduceFunction1,
            { out: "sales_total_by_country_and_isrc" }
                )

db.sales_total_by_country_and_isrc.find()           

mongoexport --csv -d test -c sales_total_by_country_and_isrc -q '{value: {$ne: 0}}' -f "_id.video_id","_id.isrc","_id.country","value" -o sales_total_by_country_and_isrc.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that one of your amount_payable value was stored as a string. If so, then Array.sum will concatenate as a sum.

You could test using:

```
db.sales_total_by_country_and_isrc.find( { video_id: <the video_id in question>,
                                           isrc: <the isrc in question>,
                                           country: <the country in question>,
                                           amount_payable: {$type: 2 }
                                       } )
```

where $type: 2 would check for String type.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem those lines were store as strings when the raw data was imported. How can I then ensure when I import, these are forces to integers?

Comment: Hi Ryan -- Unfortunately, I don't think there is an option to convert the string to a number with mongoimport. The only thing I can think of is either to update those rows where the amount_payable is a string before starting the map/reduce or handle the different types within your map-reduce, although performance-wise, it may be painful.

Comment: I'll give that a go. If I can identify the values that are strings first and then convert I imagine it will be fairly quick. Thanks again.